# Time ago function return bad time

Tags: javascript, datetime

I write a function like below to return `... time ago` in my app:

```js
//update time os in this format: "2021-03-22T20:35:03.000Z"
function timeAgo(updateTime) { 

  var date = new Date(updateTime);

  var ms = (new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime();
  var seconds = Math.floor(ms / 1000);
  var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
  var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
  var months = Math.floor(days / 30);
  var years = Math.floor(months / 12);

  if (ms === 0) {
    return 'Just now';
  } if (seconds < 60) {
    return seconds + ' seconds ago';
  } if (minutes < 60) {
    return minutes + ' minutes ago';
  } if (hours < 24) {
    return hours + ' hours ago';
  } if (days < 30) {
    return days + ' days ago';
  } if (months < 12) {
    return months + ' months ago';
  } else {
    return years + ' years ago';
  }
}

let tenSecsAgo = new Date(Date.now() - 1e4).toISOString();
console.log(`${new Date(tenSecsAgo).toString()} was ${timeAgo(tenSecsAgo)}`);
```

and I have one question, why when my `updateTime` is updated a few seconds ago, then this function return me e.q. `-3623 seconds ago`? Can someone tell me what is wrong here? Thanks for any help!,

ps. i do not want to use some library to get this `time ago` because i want to get so smallest `node_modules` in my app

Comment: Is `updateTime` in the future?

Comment: Or different time zones, at specific times, can appear to be in the future. (e.g. EST and  EDT, when changing could look almost an hour off, which is what ~3623 seconds looks like)

Comment: @cbr no, this time is in the past

Comment: Add console.log everywhere. Log both the `updateTime` and the current time (`new Date()`) and see if they look right. Log the parsed `date` and see if it looks right.

Comment: `(new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()` can be `Date.now() - date`. :-)

Comment: Until you can post code that reproduces the error, suggestions will only be guesses. 22 March 2021 was a Monday, nowhere I now of changes to DST on a Monday, and not at some time between 10:00 that morning and 10:00 the following Tuesday (the range of possible local times based on standard time zone offsets).